Can anyone see a way to linearize this function for linear regression?
I have the following function:
$$f(x) = \dfrac{a_1}{(x+b_1)^2+c_1} + \dfrac{a_2}{(x+b_2)^2+c_2}.$$
From multiple measurements of $f$ at known $x$ values I would like find the values of $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2$ which will cause the function to match my measurements as closely as possible. I would like to use linear regression however this means I need to transform the function into a form where linear regression can be used. I have seen people take the natural log, inverse, exponential of both sides in order to rearrange the equation into linear form. Is there some similar technique I can use on my function?
An example of what I am trying to do is at the end of this video (9:15) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jezAWd6GFRg&t=628s
He is able to linearize the gaussian curve equation by taking the natural log of both sides.
I already understand how to optimize for the 6 variables using an iterative approach such as gradient descent - I want to understand if a non-iterative approach can be used. Is my problem solvable using linear regression?
Thanks in advance.
EDIT:
Changed denominator of the function slightly.
This Desmos page hopefully demonstrates what I would like to achieve more clearly and numerical data is given:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6yjsnreh5r
I want to calculate what a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2 are through linear regression using the data. As a real life example imagine x is the age of people in our sample and f(x) is amount of Lego purchased per year in kilograms, (there are two peaks around the age of 10 and 30 in the Desmos linked example).

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Wouldn't Tailor expansion work?

Thanks for the response Al.G. I think your Taylor expansion idea is the principle behind non-linear regression. I am keen to find a more elegant solution which does not involve an approximation of the function.

Taylor expansion is absolutely not the idea behind non-linear regression.

They are a lot of methods  to transform the function into a form where linear regression can be used. Each one is more or less convenient depending on the kind of data (extent, scatter, etc.). The question is too wide. Be concrete. Joint to your question a representative example of data (numerical, not graphical).

@JJacquelin. Hi Jean ! I was waiting for you here.

@Claude Leibovici. Hi Claude ! Happy to hearing from you.

@JJacquelin. Thankyou I really appreciate your feedback on this. I have updated my question now, are you able to advise on some of the methods I can look at to transform this function?

Can you just clarify, are you interested in getting a set of coefficients to match your data as closely as possible (by some metric), or are you specifically interested in transformation to some linear form?

Hi @Chris Lewis, thanks for your input. I am interested in transformation to linear form for my specific function (so I can then obtain coefficients using linear regression). I am already aware of the draw-backs of transforming my data. I am also already aware of non-linear regression techniques which could also solve for the coefficients which best match the data.

@HazCam it seems others in this comment section are better placed to answer than I am. Perhaps this is one of the drawbacks you mention, but you may want to consider the effect of any transformation on the exact nature of the errors you're dealing with. It looks as though you want to transform into a linear or polynomial setting, and then minimise the sum of the squares of the errors in that setting. But it may be that you weight the errors in an undesirable way. You might also want to bear in mind that this could be conceptually harder to explain than a nonlinear regression.

The proposed method of linearisation below is rather simplistic :
$$y=\frac{a_1}{(x+b_1)^2+c_1}+\frac{a_2}{(x+b_2)^2+c_2}$$
$$((x+b_1)^2+c_1)((x+b_2)^2+c_2)y=a_1((x+b_2)^2+c_2)+a_2((x+b_1)^2+c_1)$$
Expending and rearranging the terms leads to a LINEAR EQUATION on this form :
$$Ax^4y+Bx^3y+Cx^2y+Dxy+Ey+Fx^2+Gx=1$$
"Linear" means wrt the coefficients $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$ ( Not wrt the functions of $x,y$).
$$A=\frac{1}{a_1(b_2^2+c_2)+a_2(b_1^2+c_1)} \tag 1$$
$$B=\frac{2(b_1+b_2)}{a_1(b_2^2+c_2)+a_2(b_1^2+c_1)} \tag 2$$
$$C=\frac{b_1^2+b_2^2+4b_1b_2+c_1+c_2}{a_1(b_2^2+c_2)+a_2(b_1^2+c_1)} \tag 3$$
$$D=\frac{2(c_1b_2+c_2b_1+b_1^2b_2+b_2^2b_1)}{a_1(b_2^2+c_2)+a_2(b_1^2+c_1)} \tag 4$$
$$E=\frac{b_2^2c_1+b_1^2c_2+b_1^2b_2^2+c_1c_2}{a_1(b_2^2+c_2)+a_2(b_1^2+c_1)} \tag 5$$
$$F=\frac{a_1+a_2}{a_1(b_2^2+c_2)+a_2(b_1^2+c_1)} \tag 6$$
$$G=\frac{2(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)}{a_1(b_2^2+c_2)+a_2(b_1^2+c_1)} \tag 7$$
From your data $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$ can be computed thanks to linear regression :

Then the more difficult part of the work is to compute $a_1,b_1,c_1,a_2,b_2,c_2$ from the equations $1-7$.
They are seven equations but six unknowns. In fact the equations are not independent. One can take only six equations or any six different linerar combinations from the seven equations. The result will be always almost the same if the data is not at all scattered. If the data is scattered the result will be more or less different depending on the extend of the scatter.
From Eqs.1-7 boring calculus leads to this equation to which $X=b_1$ is one root :
$$r_4X^4+r_3X^3+r_2X^2+r_1X+r_0=0$$
$r_4=64A^2(F^2E-A)\simeq -4.330751718971315 * 10^{-14}$
$r_3= 64AB(A-F^2E)\simeq -3.473262878649127 * 10^{-12}$
$r_2=4F^2D^2A-20B^2A+16A^2GD+16F^2B^2E+16ABEFG\simeq -1.000886236627868 * 10^{-10}$
$r_1= 2B^3-2F^2D^2B-8B^2EFG-8ABDG\simeq-1.221033088114019  * 10^{-9}$
$r_0=EG^2B^2+BGD^2F+B^2GD-G^2D^2A\simeq -5.241656221642709 * 10^{-9}$
A solver of polynomial equation is required. Four roots are obtained :
$$b_1\simeq -10.00000000033191 $$
$$b_2\simeq -30.10000000006216$$
$b_3\simeq -20.05000000019703-0.31911127071001*i$
$b_4\simeq -20.05000000019703+0.31911127071001*i$
Of course the complex roots are rejected.
$$a_1=\frac{2b_1F-G}{2A(b_1-b_2)}\simeq 100.0000000127709$$
$$a_2=-\frac{F}{A}-a_1 \simeq 79.99999999803072$$
$$c_1=\frac{-8AFb_1^4+4BFb_1^3-(BG+8A)b_1^2+2(B-DF)b_1+DG}{8AFb_1^2-4BFb_1+BG}\simeq 10.00000000087639$$
$$c_2=c_1+\frac{Bb_1}{2A}-\frac{B^2}{4A^2}+\frac{D-c_1B}{2Ab_1}\simeq 4.999999990266133$$

COMMENT :
The above example gives a false idea about the reliability of the method of linearisation because the data is not scattered. With scattered data the result should be much worse. Try with more realistic examples and see.
One cannot expect results as good as non-linear regression. At least the above method with linearisation might produce the order of magnitude of the parameters which could be used as initial values for iterative non-linear regression process.
IN ADDITION : Screenshot as requested in comments.


Thankyou so much this is exactly what I was looking for :) I was overlooking the fact that the functions of x and y can be functions of both x AND y, I was limiting my options by trying to keep x and y separate. Thankyou also for your work on solving for the parameters after the matrix computation.

I updated my answer with the new function and with a reduced degree of polynomial equation.

Hi again @JJacquelin. I know you said the calculus is boring but I am fascinated by how you managed to derive the r coefficients in the polynomial of X in such a way that the real roots of the polynomial give b1 and b2. Is there a name for the technique you used? What was your thought process/goal when producing these equations? I imagine that you are a bit of a calculus wizard and a lot of it was intuition. Also, thanks for the updated answer.

There is nothing wizard. I guess that the two real roots and the two complex roots of the fourth degree polynomial equation appear only if the scatter of the data is low. This is probably not the general case with more scattered data. In fact the equations where obtained with the help of the software "MathCad". If you need it I could joint a screen copy of this part of the calculus.

I am going to try your solution on data with varying degrees of scatter/noise and see if the roots are always there. Ok I feel a bit less dumb knowing they were derived using MathCad, I was racking my brain for an intuitive derivation. Yes please any screenshots would be great.

@HazCam. In addition to my answer a screenshot of the equations of the part from A,B,C,D,E,F,G to r0,r1,r2,r3,r4. But I doubt that will be useful. The key point is the study with various extend of scatter as you proposed. Good luck.
